# Why isn't spreading working with intersecting a generic type?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm trying to wrap a function that take an argument of some specific type to create a function that take an argument of a slightly different type.  Here is the code, slightly simplified:

```
type DifferentArgs<T> = {
    myNewArg: number;
} & T;


function f<T, U>({ myNewArg, ...t }: DifferentArgs<T>, g: (q: T) => U) {
    return g(t);
}
```

This seems logical to me: `t` will necessarily be assignable to `T`.

The compiler disagrees:

```
 'Pick<DifferentArgs<T>, Exclude<keyof T, "myNewArg">>' is 
  assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could 
  be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'
```

Can someone explain *how* there could be a different `T` and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that took me a long time.

Here's the problem.  Imagine the above code *did* compile.  Further imagine you are trying to call `f()` like so:

```
type KillerType = {
  myNewArg(): void;
}

f( k, (kt: KillerType) => kt.myNewArgs());
```

Now there is no value you can use for `k` that makes sense.  It would have to have the property `myNewArg` both be a number and a void-valued function, a clear impossibility.   Even ignoring the type-checking problem, `f()` would call the anonymous function without any `myNewArg` value at all.

It can be fixed:

```
type DifferentArgs<T> = {
    myNewArg: number;
} & T; 

type SameArgs<T> = Omit<T, 'myNewArg'>;

function f<T, U>({ myNewArg, ...t }: DifferentArgs<T>,
                 g: (q: SameArgs<T>) => U): U {
    return g(t);
}
```

Basically, you have to promise the compiler that the parameter to `g` will never need a property called `myNewArg` so the [conflict can never arise](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgMwRAThAdsAgig5gZwB4AVAPigF4oBvAKCgagFsQA5CAdx1wC4p0ArkwBGqANy0AvlABkUYmKi1aoSFADKAQyYRuRMpSgB5JnGAkANFADkLdlzzXSE2ggHoAxsDgB7dFARLKABVUgAKamY2Tm4rADoE4ChJPngkVAxsPH1SC3pGAsKC3igwgEc+LR09ElIASkpyYLq+YJp8hjRgARR-XDDgOolJZRVwaABpOAAbadRiccM6BjsYvDCWqAA3HzgAE2HlBDCoAGsrMNPgPinZ+fGGinIruNWHfrqh2iA).